# You are taking a multiple-choice test with n questions each of which has 4 alternatives. You have mastered 60% of the material

Tags: probability, statistics

You are taking a multiple-choice test with n questions each of which has 4 alternatives. You have mastered 60% of the material. Assume this means that you have a 0.6 chance of knowing the answer to a random test question, and that if you don’t know the answer to a question then you randomly select among the four answer choices. Assume that this holds for each question, independent of the others, and assume that each correct answer gives 1 point and wrong answers give 0 points, the score is the sum of all points.  For each answer define a random variable Xi (i=1,2,...,n) that takes the value 1 if the  ith answer is correct and 0 otherwise. 
a.What is the probability that you answer a particular question correctly? 
b.What is your expected score on the exam? 
c.Write down a formula for the probability mass function (pmf) for one particular X, obtain the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for Xi and plot the CDF 
WORK: for my work so far I have A = Knowing the answer B = All choices are equal and C = Student answers correctly. P(A) = .6, P(B) = .25 I am looking for P(A|C)? = P(C|A)P(A)/P(C)? Other than that I am kind of lost

Comment: for my work so far I have A = Knowing the answer B = All choices are equal and C = Student answers correctly. P(A) = .6, P(B) = .25 I am looking for P(A|C)? = P(C|A)P(A)/P(C)? Other than that I am kind of lost

Comment: You should include your attempt in the question itself.

Comment: Ok sorry about that I am new to this site

Comment: What do you mean by "Write down a formula for the probability mass function (pmf) for one particular X"? $X$ is a random variable that can take on several different values. Do you mean $n$?

Comment: I believe for (a) you're looking for $P(C) = P(C | A)P(A) + P(C | B)P(B)$ (because $B = A^c$).

Comment: So would it just be .6 +(.4*.25)?

Comment: @WhiteMamba Yep!

Comment: for part b. would it just be .7n?

Comment: Yep, this is a binomial distribution with mean $np=n\cdot0.7$

Comment: for the pmf do I just do xi=1 and xi=0 for x=1 it is evaluated at .7 and for x=0 it is .3?

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think the $pmf$ question makes sense. With $pmf$'s you have all the possible values the random variable $X$ can take on. In this case, those values are $x\in\{0,..,n\}$

Comment: Never mind, $X$ is just one particular question?

Comment: I assume so but I am not quite sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The probability that he gets a particular question correct is

$$p=\left(0.6\cdot1\right)+\left(0.4\cdot0.25\right)=0.7$$

b) This is a binomial distribution with mean $np$

c)

Assuming $X$ is a random variable taking on the value $1$ if the answer is correct and $0$ if the answer is incorrect...

$$ p_{X}(x)=  
\begin{cases} 
0.7 & x =1 \\
0.3 & x=0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

d)

$$ F_{X}(x)=  
\begin{cases} 
1 & x \geq 1 \\
0.3 & 0\leq x\lt 1 \\
0 & x \lt 0
\end{cases} $$

Note that even in the discrete case, we must account for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: for c don't you need 0 otherwise? Also for d don't you need x<0, 0<=x<1, and x>=1?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I will fix that.

Comment: Also how do you get 1? I know that's the right answer im confused on how, for x>=1

Comment: There is more than one correct way to notate the cdf. And what do you mean?

Comment: for the cdf you are saying that over one I thought it was .7 but why is .3 added in as well? Might be a dumb question but I dont know

Comment: $P(X=0)=0.3$ so the cdf takes on the value $0.3$.  $P(X=1)=0.7$ so the cdf takes on the value $0.3+0.7=1$

Comment: Awesome thank you for all your help!!

Comment: You're welcome! Since it helped, please take a second to accept my answer.